# Single table against multiple tables for similar type of data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, table-structure

I need some suggestion over this approach - please see examples below.

I have table structure as below

```
data_jobtype
id, identifier (varchar), description (varchar), userid (int)

data_statustype
id, identifier (varchar), description (varchar), userid (int)

data_usertype
id, identifier (varchar), description (varchar), userid (int)

data_roletype
id, identifier (varchar), description (varchar), userid (int)
```

there are about 10 more similar tables. Then I had another idea and created a new table like

```
data_types
id, identifier (varchar), description (varchar), userid (int), typetype (varchar)
```

this table takes all the data from the above tables and `typetype` fields tells which type of data it is. Eg. `typetype` = 'jobtype' or `typetype` = 'roletype`

this second approach works just fine but when I was writing a query to refer to the same table twice to create a join on two different types of `types` I realised I need to understand if querying single table multiple times in a query is better than multiple tables. Example query:

```
select u.*, dt.description usertype_desc, dt2.description roletype_desc
from users u 
left join data_types dt on dt.identifier = u.user_identifier and dt.typetype = 'usertype'
left join data_types dt2 on dt2.identifier = u.role_identifier and dt2.typetype = 'roletype'
Where u.status = 'live'
```

Its not only this query I am worried about. The project is still in its early days but it will eventually grow big so I have time to put the basic structure right now so I'd appreciate your comments on if I am doing it right. which approach you'd recommend over other and why? thanks

Comment: use the `EXPLAIN` keyword in MySQL to understand more about how the database plans to execute your query. This can help you broadly compare the performance of one query design against the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much simpler to link in both types in the join condition:

```
left join data_types dt 
on dt.identifier = u.user_identifier and dt.typetype in ('usertype', 'roletype')
```

I don't think there are performance implications for the single table approach.  The question is what makes for more readable queries.

Comment: Actually - in this example, there are two different types of identifier in user table - id_usertype, and id_roletype so what you suggested wouldn't work here unfortunately

Comment: Why would it not work?  It returns 2 rows... is there a requirement to return only one row?

Comment: The user table is id (int), id_usertype (id from data_types), id_roletypes, name and rest of the columns......so you see there are 2 different columns which refer to same identifier field in the data_types table .... now that if i want to list all the users with their usertype (desc col from data_types), and roletype .... it'll return multiple rows?? or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, this answer will return multiple rows.  For a single row, you'd have to join the `data_types` table multiple times, just like you had to when types where in different tables.

Comment: OK got it - Overall what's your thought about this approach? should I split it into multiple tables?

Comment: Either approach is fine.  I'd go with what you have now and focus on implementing features that provide value to your customer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this approach is going to give you some convoluted SQL that is harder to write and more importantly harder to maintain over the long term.

Unless you see the same "stuff" being duplicated in all of these tables -  in which case you would want to separate "type_type" out into a join table - I would recommend sticking with the tables that accurately describe what they hold.

Also over time it's likely you're going to want to add new fields for statustype, and different fields for jobtype, etc. Eventually these table structures will be less and less similar.